# How can I use UpNavigation (Back button) to navigate from one page to its corresponding previous page in android eclipse

Tags: android, back-button, up-navigation

I need to navigate from one page to its corresponding previous page(there are more than one previous page for current page in my app) . How can I implement it using Up Navigation / Back button.

Answer (score 1):

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Setup parent in Manifest file and then on Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

or You can call `finish()` instead of

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding) or [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

Then simply add [setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home).

Comment: Will it enable to move to specified previous button? If so,could you please  give me a sample code this?

Answer (score 0):

On activities it is by default getting back to previous using back button, but no up button. If you want up, put in Manifest:

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

on Fragments:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack("Tag");
. . .
```

Comment: Will it enable to move to specified previous button? If so,could you please give me a sample code this?

Comment: I don't understand hmmm maybe post some codes you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can specify parent activities in the manifest

Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName attribute in the  element

If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a  element inside the . Then specify the parent activity as the value for android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY, matching the android:parentActivityName attribute.

For example:

```
 <application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

With the parent activity declared this way, you can use the NavUtils APIs to synthesize a new back stack by identifying which activity is the appropriate parent for each activity.

You can refer [How to implement the Android ActionBar back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108774/how-to-implement-the-android-actionbar-back-button) for implement UpNavigation in your activity

I hope it helps.