# Back button with text and title in android action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back-button

I am not using `Toolbar` or `ActionbarActivity` . I am using plain activity . My activity is having an actionbar . I want to customize it in such way that the title of the activity align in middle and there is a back button with some text  . Like this image

[image]

. I am using a custom layout for my actionbar and the design is ok , back button is working too . But the problem is the text with back button is clickable .

Here is what I have tried

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_title);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The layout for `custom_actionbar_title`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="16.0"
    android:weightSum="16.0">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Incidents"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/backButtonText"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="Detail"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108774/how-to-implement-the-android-actionbar-back-button take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit it according to yourself :

make a separate xml :let's say app_bar xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_back_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:gravity="left">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@mipmap/back"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="end|center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_back_image"/>

    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"

        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_sort_white_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/filter_img_id"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Include the above layout in your main_activity.xml //you can change according to your xml:like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@color/faintwhite"
    android:id="@+id/container">
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

If you are using fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mini_detail, container, false);
        findAllId();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(MiniDetail.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);// action bar
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        TextView tv= (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        tv.setText("MUMBA");
```

if you are using Activity :

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(SplashScreen.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);// action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        TextView tv= (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        tv.setText("Welcome");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

     "your back button & textview code here"

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```