# Why pressed back arrow button will make Home of ButtonNavigationView's category images disappear?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-sqlite, start-activity

I would like to know why pressed back arrow button will make Home of ButtonNavigationView's category images disappear?
Back arrow I used "startActivity(Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java))"to go back Mainactivity.kt then it use "supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, selectedFragment!!)
                       .commitNow()" go to HomeFragment.kt

MainActivity.kt

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener, CoroutineScope {
        val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
        private lateinit var job: Job
        override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
            get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

        private val RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 100

        var signInButton: MenuItem? = null
        var signOutButton: MenuItem? = null

        lateinit var vm :SavedStateViewModel
        companion object{
            var user: FirebaseUser? = null
            var selectedFragment: Fragment? = null

        }


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateStart: onCreateStart");
            job = Job()
            vm = ViewModelProvider(this,SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, this))
                .get(SavedStateViewModel::class.java)

                //check if user had signed in
                checkCurrentUser()

                //Set bottom_navigation_view
                bottomNavView()


        }



        private fun bottomNavView() {
            bottom_nav_view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.navigation_home -> selectedFragment = HomeFragment.instance

                    R.id.navigation_add_photos -> selectedFragment = AddPhotosFragment.instance

                    R.id.navigation_profile -> selectedFragment = ProfileFragment.instance
                }
    //            Log.d(TAG, "selectedFragment: $selectedFragment");

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, selectedFragment!!)
                    .commitNow()


                true
            }
        }
private fun checkCurrentUser() {

           // [START check_current_user]
           user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCurrentUser()user:$user ");
           if (user == null) {
               // No user is signed in
               signInButton?.isVisible = true
               signOutButton?.isVisible = false
               signIn()
           } else {
               // User is signed in
               signOutButton?.isVisible = true
               signInButton?.isVisible = false
               Log.d(TAG, "selectedFragment:$selectedFragment ");
               if (selectedFragment == null) {
                   directToHomeFragment()
               } else {
                   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, selectedFragment!!)
                       .commitNow()
               }

           }
           // [END check_current_user]

    }
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(),CoroutineScope {
    lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    companion object {
        val instance by lazy {
            HomeFragment()
        }
        var categoryDatabaseAdded:Boolean = false
        var categoryListLiveData:LiveData<MutableList<CategoryDesign>>? = null
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.getMainCategoryDesign().observe(this, Observer {
            //TODO once add to category database
            //add firestore category data into SQLite
            categoryListLiveData = SearchDesignerDatabase.getDatabase(context!!)
                .getCategoryDAO().getCategory()

            if (!categoryDatabaseAdded || categoryListLiveData == null) {
                it?.let {
                    it.forEach {
                        context?.let { it1 ->
                            launch {
                                SearchDesignerDatabase.getDatabase(it1)
                                    .getCategoryDAO().addCategory(it)
                                categoryDatabaseAdded = true
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            //add category data into Home Fragment RecyclerView Category
            recycler_category.apply {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
                adapter =
                    CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(
                        it
                    )
            }
        })

    }



}
```

CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity.kt

```
class CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity::class.java.simpleName

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_detail_recycler_view)

        var intent = getIntent()
        Log.d(TAG, "Intent:$intent ");
        var categoryDesignID = intent.getStringExtra("categoryDesignID")
        Log.d(TAG, "categoryDesignID: $categoryDesignID");

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.title = categoryDesignID

        //query categorized
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("uploadedImages")
            .whereEqualTo("categoryDesignID", categoryDesignID)
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                Log.d(TAG, "uploadedImagesQuerySnapshot:$querySnapshot ");
                if (querySnapshot != null && !querySnapshot.isEmpty) {
                    var uploadedImagesList = mutableListOf<UploadedImages>()
                    for (doc in querySnapshot.documents) {
                        val uploadedImages = doc.toObject(UploadedImages::class.java)
                        uploadedImagesList.add(uploadedImages!!)
                    }

                    category_detail_recycler_view.apply {
                        setHasFixedSize(true)
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity)
                        adapter = DetailRecyclerAdapter(uploadedImagesList)
                    }

                }
            }




    }
    //ActionBar back arrow button
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        //TODO back arrow pressed back to home
//        onBackPressed()

        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java))

        return true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java))
        /*supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.nav_host_fragment,
            HomeFragment.instance
        ).commit()*/

    }
}
```

CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.kt

```
class CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(var categoryDesigns: List<CategoryDesign>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.categoryViewHolder>()  {



   inner class categoryViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
       var categoryImage = itemView.category_image
       var categoryName = itemView.category_name
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): categoryViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.categories_design, parent, false)
        return categoryViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categoryDesigns.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: categoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val categoriesItem = categoryDesigns.get(position)
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(categoriesItem.designImage)
            .into(holder.categoryImage)
        holder.categoryName.text = categoriesItem.designTitle
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO Show RecyclerView
            val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("categoryDesignID",categoriesItem.categoryDesignID)
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the `onActivityCreated` to `onViewCreated`? Because you want to load the data once the view is being created, not the activity. Because when the `Intent` is starting the `MainActivity` through the back button, the activity isn't being created again, unless you end the activity when you leave it.

Comment: I would actually recommend that you don't `startActivity` on the back press. Android should handle it if you specify which Activity you should go back to on the back press.

Comment: @Nizar I have tried code put in onViewCreated, but still has the same problem.

Comment: the change should be made to `CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity` as the Back Button Implementation is what is causing this unusual behavior. You need to add `onOptionsItemSelected` that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471504/5512292)

Comment: @Nizar I have tried
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
//                startActivity(Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java))
            return true
            }
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }


    }
in CategoryDetailRecyclerViewActivity.kt
but this cause force close app.

Comment: @Nizar Later, I changed Glide to Picasso, images can show correctly.Thank you very much. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later, I changed Glide to Picasso, images can show correctly.